# OpenCV capture delay in parallel programming

Tags: opencv, parallel-processing, openmp, tbb

I'm trying to capture from webcam in OpenCV parallel programming.

When I capture a frame without parallel block, it works with 60fps.

But when it works in parallel block like OpenMP or TBB, it works only 10~20fps.

Especially, `VideoCapture::grab()` function takes more double or triple time in parallel block.

There are capture programming code using OpenMP or TBB below.

Using openMP

```
#pragma omp parallel
#pragma omp sections
{
#pragma omp section
{
    clock_t a1 = clock();
    cap.grab();
    printf("grab : %f\n", double(clock() - a1) / double(CLOCKS_PER_SEC));
    cap.retrieve(Origin);
    printf("cam : %f\n", double(clock() - a1) / double(CLOCKS_PER_SEC));
}

#pragma omp section
{
    clock_t a2 = clock();
    BOriginal.copyTo(OriginA);
    cvtColor(AAOri, HSOriginA, COLOR_BGR2HSV);
    HSOriginA.copyTo(HSOrigin);
}
}
```

Using TBB

```
task_scheduler_init init;

parallel_invoke([capture, Origin]()->void {

    clock_t aas = clock();
    cap.grab();
    printf("grab time : %f\n", double(clock() - aas) / double(CLOCKS_PER_SEC));
    cap.retrieve(Origin);
    printf("cam time : %f\n", double(clock() - aas) / double(CLOCKS_PER_SEC));

},
[BOriginal, OriginA, HSOriginA, HSOrigin]()->void {
    clock_t a2 = clock();
    BOriginal.copyTo(OriginA);
    cvtColor(OriginA, HSOriginA, COLOR_BGR2HSV);
    HSOriginA.copyTo(HSOrigin);

});
```

In OpenMP, capture programming block whether in `omp master` or in `omp single`, `omp section`, it works the same.

How can I capture(`grab()`, `retrieve()`) without delay in parallel programming.

My environment is ARM processor and Linux Fedora 3.10 Kernel.

Comment: What's the point of parallelizing this phase at all? It seems rather unlikely you can start acquiring a frame before you finished acquiring the previous one. Much less so with a simple "least common denominator" wrapper around multiple libraries such as the one that OpenCV provides.

Comment: @DanMašek Thanks for your reply! I want to acquire a frame while another function working. Just all. Maybe I will find cause from and modify OpenCV library. Thanks!

Comment: OK, it might make sense to parallelize the processing of the frames, however keep in mind that many OpenCV functions already are parallelized, so the gains might not be significant. It does however make sense to decouple the frame acquisition from the processing. I don't use OpenMP or TBB, but the the way I would structure this would be one thread that acquires frames from the camera and feeds some (synchronized) queue which is consumed by one or more consumer threads that then process the frames.

Comment: @DanMašek First of all, Thanks for your reply. Hmm... I will keep in mind your advice that gains might not be significant. Also, I think the key solution for this problem is a thread. When I monitor a thread consumption in working only capture a frame loop, thread is used just one continually. But capture a frame in working with OpenMP(only one sections or master section), a lot of  thread alternate with each other. I will look for cause upon your advice. Thanks a lot!